# Solr how to write a facet.query text field value

Tags: solr

I am thoroughly confused and lost due to being unable to know what to enter in this **facet.query** field when using Solr

[image]

I want to do a sum of all the documents that are returned, summing up this TotalPaxCount and AdultPaxCount values?

How can I do this using the GUI in the Solr web interface. The very limited examples seem to use curl requests and I have tried what they put in the facet.query and its constantly errors.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use the JSON Facet syntax in a plain `facet.query` field; these are different APIs. Depending on what you actually want to do, you might want to either use the JSON Facet API (i.e. if you want to generate the sums for another facet key), or use the `stats` API (if you want to generate the sums for a single query).

Comment: Ok so how do I write a facet in that text box for summing TotalPaxCount and AdultPaxCount each? What are these other APIs?, at the moment I want to query via this ui.

Comment: If you only want to sum those two across the entire collection, use `stats=true&stats.field=TotalPaxCount&stats.field=AdultPaxCount`. If you want to apply the sums to buckets (i.e. divided by another field), use the `json.facet` parameter (if you need to have it in the URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to see what the original code was creating and then gave up trying to use the web UI interface! using curl I could make a call like this, in windows I had to put it all on one line like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/query -d "{\"filter\": \"\",\"query\":\"ResortId:(229) AND ArrivalDate:[2022-10-24T00:00:00Z TO 2022-10-30T23:59:59Z] AND IsActive:True AND *:*\", \"limit\": 0,\"offset\": 0,\"fields\": \"\",\"facet\": {\"ResortId\": { \"type\": \"terms\",\"field\": \"ResortId\", \"limit\": -1, \"minCount\": 0, \"facet\": { \"Total\": \"sum(TotalCount)\", \"AdultCount\": \"sum(AdultCount)\", \"ChildCount\": \"sum(ChildCount)\", \"InfantCount\": \"sum(InfantCount)\" }}}}'
```

On a linux machine I believe you could do this curl command, which is more readable. I think this helps show the structure that is expect from solr, as was very confusing trying to understand the documentation.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/query -d '
{
    "filter": "",
    "query": "ResortId:(229) AND ArrivalDate:[2022-10-24T00:00:00Z TO 2022-10-30T23:59:59Z] AND IsActive:True AND *:*",
    "limit": 0,
    "offset": 0,
    "fields": "",
    "facet": {
        "ResortId": {
            "type": "terms",
            "field": "ResortId",
            "limit": -1,
            "minCount": 0,
            "facet": {
                "Total": "sum(TotalCount)",
                "AdultCount": "sum(AdultCount)",
                "ChildCount": "sum(ChildCount)",
                "InfantCount": "sum(InfantCount)"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```